# Enable client side validation is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Actually i am using server side validation and saw article that only adding link to java script file and using  <%Html.ClientValidationEnabled = true%> will automatically enable client side validation but first of all i am using Visual Web Developer 2010 Express 4.0.30319 
and here it show error that <%Html.ClientValidationEnabled = true%> does not exist i dont know
what reference i need  for enabling this. Second i try to use 
<% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %> it is not giving any error but also not working my page is posting back and only server side validations are working.

Comment: Which JavaScript have you added in your page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following Scott Gu's excellent [blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx) about Model Validation and you should get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it

...Form fields go in here

and you need script references for MicrosoftAjax.js and MicrosoftMvcValidation.js